# Reading .txt file into a c++ stream, some strings are consist of two separate words

Tags: c++, string, txt

I have to read a subway network described in a .txt file into a graph consisting of nodes and edges for a university project, so far I've been able to read the file and automatically check for strings, doubles or ints.
Now the problem is that some station names consist of two separate words and my code will jump further to the double or int value describing the distance or time and treat that as if it were the second string of the station name.

Here's an excerpt of the .txt file  describing the format :

```
U1 Warschauer Str -> Schlesisches Tor: 0,8 2
U1 Schlesisches Tor -> Gourlitzer Bahnhof: 0,9 2
U2 Pankow -> Vinetastrasse: 0,5 1

Line Station 1 -> Station2: Distance_in_km Travel_time_in_minutes
```

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream datei("C:\\Users\\jeff\\Desktop\\Fortgeschrittene Algorithmen & Programmierung\\Berlin.txt");
    std::string zeile;

    while (std::getline(datei, zeile))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < zeile.size(); i++)
        {
            if (zeile[i] == ',')
            {
                zeile[i] = '.';
            };

            if (zeile[i] == '-' || zeile[i] == '>')
            {
                zeile[i] = ' ';
            };
            
            if (zeile[i] == ':')
            {
                zeile[i] = ' ';
            };


        }


        std::stringstream ausgabe(zeile);
        std::string linie, station1a, station1b, station2a, station2b;
        double c;
        int d;

        ausgabe >> linie >> station1a >> station1b >> station2a >> station2b >> c >> d;
        std::cout << "Linie : " << linie << " StationsnameSource : " << station1a << " " << station1b << " StationsnameDestination : " << station2a << " " << station2b << " Entfernung in km : " << c << " Fahrtdauer in min :  " << d << "\n";
    enter code here
        
        
    }

    

    return 0;

}
```

I've made four strings for the station names, however if the station only has one name it will take the next string and just use that (for example the second station's string name or the double used for the distance)

Does someone have an idea how to solve this ?
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Your shown code shows that you are already familiar with `std::getline`, which is all that's necessary to read text containing spaces. So, what is your question, exactly?

Comment: The problem is that some station names consist of only one word or string while others consist of two. Now what I've done is automatically check for strings separated by spaces, station1a will return the first detected string, station1b the second one and so on. However if the first station name only consists of one word station1b will return the first word of the second station name. Station2b could return the double value c as a string if the second station name only has one name. I need to find a way to save both station names as a string regardless of whether they have one word or two.

Comment: According to your description: Search the station name until you find "->" or ":"

Comment: Sounds good, I will try that, thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crude code to show you the principle.

Input file, train.txt:

```
U1 Warschauer Str -> Schlesisches Tor: 0,8 2
U1 Schlesisches Tor -> Gourlitzer Bahnhof: 0,9 2
U2 Pankow -> Vinetastrasse: 0,5 1
```

Outputs:

```
Station1=U1 Warschauer Str , Station2=Schlesisches Tor
Station1=U1 Schlesisches Tor , Station2=Gourlitzer Bahnhof
Station1=U2 Pankow , Station2=Vinetastrasse
```

This needs tuning but you'll get the idea:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream ifs;
    string buf;
    int index, startIndex, n;
    char station1[36];
    char station2[36];

    ifs.open("train.txt", ifstream::in);
    while (getline(ifs, buf))           // Get characters into string, discard newline
    {
        //
        // Search for first station terminated by ->
        //
        index = 0;
        while (buf[index] != '-')
         {
            index++;
            if (buf[index] == '>')
                break;
        }
        //
        // Get first station
        //
        strncpy(station1, buf.c_str(), index);
        station1[index] = '\0';
        index += 3; // Past "-> "
        //
        // Search for next (last) station terminated by :
        //
        startIndex = index;
        while (buf[index] != ':')
            index++;
        //
        // Get next (last) station
        //
        n = index - startIndex;
        strncpy(station2, buf.c_str() + startIndex, n);
        station2[n] = '\0';
        printf("Station1=%s, Station2=%s\n", station1, station2);
    }
    ifs.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is very helpful ! I forgot to mention some station names include hyphens, for example "U6 Kurt-Schumacher-Platz -> Afrikanische Strasse: 0,6 1" so I'm currently trying to modify it accordingly as I see you're  searching for a '-' char in the while loop  while (buf[index] != '-')

Comment: If so, you can upvote the post helping you.